# Link sharing - Google Caja HTML Sanitizer

Tags: html, hyperlink, xss, html-sanitizing, google-caja

I'm trying to tackle the classic "user input sanitisation" problem on my new web app and I chose to use Google Caja's HTML Sanitizer server-side for this task.

Although the implementation + testing went fine, I still have some questions :

- 1) I could only find the HTML4 definitions, does this mean that HTML5 tags wouldn't be safe ?

I did some tests with HTML 5 specific tag / attribute XSS's and although none of them worked I'm not 100% sure that some untested ones wouldn't work.

- 2) Google Caja doesn't seem too active anymore, would this constitute a security issue ?
- 3) I want my users to be able to share links, how would I be able to do this in a safe way that passes Google Caja's filters ? (like StackOverflow)
- 4) How does Caja handle Unicode ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) I could only find the HTML4 definitions, does this mean that HTML5 tags wouldn't be safe ?

We have added HTML5 support in the past few months. Please let us know if anything is missing.

> 2) Google Caja doesn't seem too active anymore, would this constitute a security issue ?

Are you perhaps looking in the wrong place? [We're quite busy, as you can see here.](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/list)

> 3) I want my users to be able to share links, how would I be able to do this in a safe way that passes Google Caja's filters ? (like StackOverflow)

You can supply a URI policy which permits or rejects outgoing links.

> 4) How does Caja handle Unicode ?

Correctly, I should hope. If things don't work, please [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/entry).