# input pattern attribute not working when served using Google HtmlService

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-caja

I would really like to use native html5 validation for some simple forms served using Google Apps HtmlService.

```
<form><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{6}" /><input type="submit" value="try it" /></form>
```

In jsfiddle the form works as expected: An input not matching six digits results in a validation prompt that is browser specific. However the exact same code served from Google Apps using HtmlService:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<form><input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{6}" /><input type="submit" value="try it" /></form>');
}
```

results in the form showing correctly, but no validation on the input. It can be tested [here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzsl5Xw8wKgGftQ-smrI_zDX5SuhtWh5IImI_EahquCO5lU7YVa/exec). I have also tried setting the pattern attribute using a script; this also failed.

The browser used in each case was the same, with the positive result on jsfiddle proving that the browser correctly supports the pattern attribute.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've been Caja'd. From [HTML Service Restrictions Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions)

> To protect users from being served malicious HTML or JavaScript, Apps
>   Script relies on the [Caja Compiler](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) to sanitize and sandbox
>   HTML-service web apps or custom user interfaces for Google Docs,
>   Sheets, and Forms.

When you look at the browser source for your web app the Caja compiler turns the form field into:

```
<input type="text" data-caja-pattern="[0-9]{6}">
```

the `data-caja` prefix preventing the browser detecting the pattern.

According to [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17303148/1027723) HTML5 support has been added to Caja so it might be worth [filing a bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/list)

Comment: Thank you for helping out with this. I suspected it might be Caja related, but www seems to think Caja supports html5. I will post a bug report as you suggest and see what happens. Cheers, Mark.

Comment: The Caja people have acknowledged it as a bug and indicate that it is easily fixable. I will post here again when it is fixed.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the update. For others the ticket is here https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1900

Comment: The html5 attributes now seem work as expected. I have tested the pattern and required attributes along with the email type. However, a new problem has arisen, namely that the html5 validation is triggered onsubmit but google htmlservice uses onclick for form submission via google.script.run as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) which prevents html5 validation from working. In sum, the attributes work but html5 validation with htmlservice seems to be impossible still. Any ideas will be welcome!